# Смена URL, ajax, обратная совместимость

Tags: url, ajax, html5, javascript

Здравствуйте. У меня тут созрело несколько вопрос, которые не дают покоя в последнее время.
Итак:

1. При изначальном изменении ссылки с "../home.php" на "../home" методом window.history.replaceState() заметно изначальное состояние URL (т.е. "../home.php") и последующее "мигание" при смене на второе состояние. Каким способ это убрать? mod_rewrite или есть альтернативные варианты?
2. При загрузке нового контента методом AJAX меняю URL через window.history.replaceState(). Есть какие-то варианты, при котором ссылка вида "../home" будет открывать страницу "../home.php"?

Спасибо всем, кто обратит внимание на мои вопросы!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это очень глупо вам не кажется? Какой смысл в ajax подгрузке, если все равно подгружаете страничку полностью? 
Стоит думаю привести пару кусков кода сюда.

Вообще, это делается с помощью mod_rewrite, по сиему здравомыслию, должна быть одна страничка, допустим index.php, в ней уже case\if или на что хватит ваших знаний будет лоудится не статическая часть странички, допустим:

```
< head>< title>я статический титул странички< /title>< /head>
< body>
Я статическая надпись, к примеру меню
< div id="content">
    < ? if(isset($_GET['link'])) 
          include "/pages/" . $_GET['link'].".php";
       else 
          include "/pages/home.php";
    ?>
< /div>
Я статический подвал.
< /body>
```

То есть, при переходе по ссылке index.php?link=about мы получим страничку из /pages/about.php

а чтобы сделать из http://мойсайт.ru/index.php?link=about к примеру  http://мойсайт.ru/about/ немного придется повозиться с реврайтом.

Тем самым дальнейшая работа с айксом пойдет более менее нормально.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ.
А кто сказал что перезагружается вся страница? Естественно перегружается только определенный блок и на основании этого блока идет изменение URL. 
Пока я для себя остановился на таком методе: (например, идет вызов ./otherpage, которой на самом деле не существует, а только ./home.php#otherpage)
1. В mod_rewrite ./otherpage трансформируется в ./home.php?data=otherpage.
2. Подхватываю JS $_GET['data']
3. Вытаскиваю Аяксом данные из otherpage
Этим фактически решился 2-ой вопрос, а вот первый пока не решен.